# How to Properly Reverse Boot Unlocking

Tags: bootloader, bootloader-lock, magisk

After following instructions to unlock a bootloader and then ones to lock it back, using Fastboot for both, my Android 7.0 phone boots with a warning saying that *Your device has failed validation* instead of the *Your device has been unlocked* which happened after unlocking but before undoing. In either case, this had an effect on the Android system and the phone appeared as *Uncertified* and failed the *SafetyNet* check.

**How can one fully undo bootloader unlocking so that the device does not fail validation and passes the SafetyNet check?**

Since it can make a difference, the device in question is a Moto G5. It was unlocked following the official instructions on the Motorola website. No new ROMS were flashed, it was only used to get Magisk to install. This resulting in a warning that the bootloader was unlocked. So I thought it just needed to be locked again and I did it with fastboot. This unfortunately resulted in another warning which says validation failed.

Comment: This depends on the device, which you didn't mention... In some devices it is not possible to relock the bootloader. Otherwise it you would likely have to root with Magisk and use Magisk Hide to bypass the SafetyNet check, but that is a cat and mouse rabbit hole, it works, then SafetyNet gets updated and Magisk fails, then Magisk get's updated, and it keeps going back and forth. Eventually there won't be a way to bypass SafetyNet. But I digress, please give us more information as to exactly what device you have by updating your original question.

Comment: @acejavelin - Updated with requested details.

Comment: You can only lock the bootloader by flashing a factory image that is the same or newer version as what you have... And we don't have a version that new with Moto firmware image leaks averaging 4-6 months behind OTA. Basically that means you cannot lock at this time.